# Read no more than size of string with scanf()

Tags: c, string, scanf, format-specifiers

Edit:  for my class I have to use `scanf`. So recommending other ways of input is not the solution I am looking for (if there is one that involves scanf).

---

If I am reading in user input for a small project (for example, a game).   Lets say I ask `would you like to play?`  This would accept a `yes` or `no` answer.  So i write up some simple code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     char string[3]; //The max number of letters for "yes".

     printf("Would you like to play?");
     scanf("%s", string);
}
```

So this code should simply ask them to input `yes` or `no`.  I am setting the length of my `char array` to size `3`.  This way it is large enough to hold `yes` and also `no`.  But if someone were to enter invalid input such as `yesss`, I know how to compare the string afterwards to handle such an event, but wouldn't this technically/possibly overwrite other local variables I have declared because it would extend outside the length of my array?  If so, is there a way to handle this to restrict 3 input characters or something?  And if not, why/how does it know to only input for the size of 3?

Comment: Probably safer to do it character by character. I'm not sure exactly if C has anything that does this for you.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that?  Would I just do a bunch of "%c" things in the "scanf" and then how would I assign them to a character of the array?  [i.e. would I need &string[0] or something].  Plus what if they enter "no", then I would only use 2 of the 3 "%c".

Comment: Doing it by yourself to handle any length entails an array that can change size at runtime and inserting characters from the input as they come while making sure not to overflow the array. Luckily, it seems `scanf` has the feature built in.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your array needs to be able to hold four `char`s, since it must also contain the 0-terminator. With that fixed, specifying a maximal length in the format,

```
scanf("%3s", string);
```

ensures that `scanf` reads no more than 3 characters.

Comment: As an aside, since the width specifier only indicates the *maximum* number of characters to read, if you need to read an *exact* number, use the above approach and then check the number of characters consumed (via [`%n`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503135/get-number-of-characters-read-by-sscanf)).

Comment: I just want to know that this is super great thing , then why do people keep saying scanf is unsafe obviously they could do this to limit input and stop buffer overflow exploit. ??

Comment: "ensures that scanf reads no more than 3 characters." --> Not quite.  `"%3s"` will first read an unlimited number of leading white-space characters.   Then it will read and save up to 3 non-white-space characters.  Finally appending a _null character_.

Comment: @SurajJain People generally recommend against scanf not because it cannot be used safely, but because it is difficult to use.  When people are first learning C,  they would be better served by learning to parse input strings than by spending time learning the foibles of the scanf format language.  scanf is rarely used in production code; in the vast majority of places it might be appropriate, C is the wrong language anyway.

Answer (score 22):

the safest way is to use

```
fgets(string, 4, stdin);
```

here you can store maximum 3 characters including one space reserved for `NULL` (`'\0'`) character.

Comment: Exactly! The Best (and most innovative) Way, tbh! Thanks

Comment: Usually the last of the "maximum 3 characters" read is the `'\n'`.

Comment: fgets() reads any characters (including whitespace) until EOF or \n. So it is not an alternative to scanf() which takes care of the format of the string read.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the *width* modifier of [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and set it to be *one less* than the size of your string, so that you ensure that space exists for the `NULL` terminator.

So, if you want to store "yes", you will firstly need a bigger array than the one you have; one with size 4, 3 characters plus 1 for the null terminator. Moreover, you should instruct `scanf()` to read no more than *size - 1* characters, where size is the length of your array, thus 3 in this case, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     char string[4];
     scanf("%3s", string);
}
```

Comment: That will scan for a digit `3`... instead use `"%3s"`

Comment: I don't even know what I was thinking back then...Thank you @JonathanLidbeck, corrected!

Comment: What if 3 is a variable? How do we do that?

Comment: @YashorajAgarwal like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/25410690/2411320

Answer (score 5):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

use the "width" modifier;

```
%[*][width][modifiers]type
```

Comment: Your link is dead but can be find in the archive https://web.archive.org/web/20211109012621/http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Updated link for the same scanf() reference page: https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/