# What does it mean scanf(%100s) in c

Tags: c, scanf

```
char variable[20][200];
printf("Enter Strings\n");
for (i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)  
scanf("%100s", variable[i]);
```

What is the function and operation logic of scanf(%100s) in here?
 I searched this command and i found some codes but i did not understand how it's 
 working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf

Comment: [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). Read starting from "*The conversion specifications in format are of two forms...*"

Comment: @Mat Except that's approaching the question from the other direction - how to limit the length read.  This question is based on not knowing that the `100` is a length limitation.  And I've yet to find an actual duplicate here on Stackoverflow, although at least one probably does exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here, the `100` is the *length modifier*, used in the conversion specifier. A length modifier specifies the size of the receiving object.

In this case, the mention of `100` limits the effective input size to be scanned to 100, which helps prevents buffer overflow in the destination due to overly long input.