# Why doesn't this program work?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, gets

When I was working on *the C Programming Language*, I wanted to do a little program to revise these previous knowledge points. And this is the program which it seems there are some problems with it.

This program is supposed to collect information from input and print it in the file "reg.txt" in a format.

However, after typing the first line and press the enter, the program quits, but I can't figure it out what's wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct profile
    {
        char *name;
        char *surname;
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    } people[10];
    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    char *line;


    fp = fopen("reg.txt", "a");
    while (fgets(line, 256, stdin)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %d/%d/%d", people[i].name, people[i].surname, &(people[i].year), &(people[i].month), &(people[i].day));
        ++i;
    }
    temp = i-1;

    for (i = 0; i <= temp; ++i)
        fprintf(fp, "NAME: %s %s\nBIRTHDAY: %d/%d/%d\n", people[i].name, people[i].surname, people[i].year, people[i].month, people[i].day);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

---

I've taken *Ed Heal*'s advice and I was aim to check the return value of 'sscanf'. What's strange is that the program doesn't really reach the 'printf' part. I thought may there are some problems with the loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *);
    struct profile
    {
        char *name;
        char *surname;
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    } people[10];
    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    char *line;
    int j;


    fp = fopen("reg.txt", "a");
    while (fgets(line, 256, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        j = sscanf(line, "%s %s %d/%d/%d", people[i].name, people[i].surname, &(people[i].year), &(people[i].month), &(people[i].day));
        ++i;
    }
    temp = i-1;

    //for (i = 0; i <= temp; ++i)
    //  fprintf(fp, "NAME: %s %s\nBIRTHDAY: %d/%d/%d\n", people[i].name, people[i].surname, people[i].year, people[i].month, people[i].day);

    printf("%d",j);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how you feed input ?

Comment: I open the cmd and run the program. Then enter these info.

Comment: turn up the warning level when you compile. `warning: ‘line’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`. iI'd also advise against using `gets`, use [`fgets`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/1540468) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after making sure `line` has allocated memory, you should be getting a segfault on your `sscanf` when it tries to write to `people[0].name` and `people[0].surname` because those pointers will be undefined.

You need to allocate memory for these strings, either statically or dynamically (with malloc).

Printing log statements can also help quite a bit to gather some insight.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    typedef struct
    {
        char name[64];
        char surname[64];
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    } profile;
    profile people[10];

    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    char line[512];

    printf("Starting profile line parser...\n");
    printf("Please enter up to 10 people in the format: (name surname year/month/day)\n");
    printf("Enter EOF to exit. (Linux: CTRL+D     Windows CTRL+Z)\n");
    fp = fopen("reg.txt", "a");
    while (gets(line) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%63s %63s %d/%d/%d", people[i].name, people[i].surname, &(people[i].year), &(people[i].month), &(people[i].day));
        ++i;
    }
    printf("Processed %d lines.\n", i);
    temp = i-1;
    for (i = 0; i <= temp; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "NAME: %s %s\nBIRTHDAY: %d/%d/%d\n", people[i].name, people[i].surname, people[i].year, people[i].month, people[i].day);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Done with profile line parser...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Because gets is deprecated, here is a fgets alternative.
Further reading on gets: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used?noredirect=1&lq=1)

EDIT: Also adding chux's buffer overflow protection.
Further reading on preventing buffer overruns with scanf: [Read no more than size of string with scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    typedef struct
    {
        char name[64];
        char surname[64];
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    } profile;
    profile people[10];

    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    char line[512];

    printf("Starting profile line parser...\n");
    printf("Please enter up to 10 people in the format: (name surname year/month/day)\n");
    printf("Enter EOF to exit. (Linux: CTRL+D     Windows CTRL+Z)\n");
    fp = fopen("reg.txt", "a");
    while (fgets(line, 512, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%63s %63s %d/%d/%d", people[i].name, people[i].surname, &(people[i].year), &(people[i].month), &(people[i].day));
        ++i;
    }
    printf("Processed %d lines.\n", i);
    temp = i-1;
    for (i = 0; i <= temp; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "NAME: %s %s\nBIRTHDAY: %d/%d/%d\n", people[i].name, people[i].surname, people[i].year, people[i].month, people[i].day);
    }
    printf("Done with profile line parser...\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%63s %63s %d/%d/%d"` would prevent possible buffer overrun.  Also consider a `gets()` alternative.

Comment: ... and check the return values from `fopen`, `sscanf`, `fprintf`

Comment: `while (fgets(line, 512, stdin) != NULL)` -> `while (i < 10 && fgets(line, 512, stdin) != NULL)` - so that the array does not overflow

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory before you use `line` with `gets`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct profile
    {
        char *name;
        char *surname;
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    };
    struct profile people[10];
    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    char line[256]; //you can also do dynamic allocation by using malloc

    fp = fopen("reg.txt", "a");
   // while (gets(line) != NULL) //use fgets instead gets
    while( fgets(line, 256, stdin) ) //specify required buffer len
    {
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %d/%d/%d", people[i].name, people[i].surname, &(people[i].year), &(people[i].month), &(people[i].day));
        ++i;
    }
    temp = i-1;

    for (i = 0; i <= temp; ++i)
        fprintf(fp, "NAME: %s %s\nBIRTHDAY: %d/%d/%d\n", people[i].name, people[i].surname, people[i].year, people[i].month, people[i].day);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As `gets()` is depreciated in C99 and no longer standard in C11, I suggest posting a solution without using the poor function `gets()`.  Perhaps `fgets()`?

Comment: Note the program will enter UB if the user enters a line of text longer than 256 characters. OP should use `fgets` or `gets_s` to prevent a buffer overflow. You also may want to zero-out the buffer too.

Comment: @chux & @Dai suggested in comment to use `fgets`, anyway updated the solution to use it.

Comment: ogu I think basically you've just progressed to the next issue. I would advise reading more about the pointers and functions you are using. You will make more progress with a solid understanding of the basics of the language.

Comment: ... and check the return value from `fopen` and `sscanf`. Ditto with `fprintf`

Comment: Problem Updated

Comment: this answer didn't correct sscanf to non allocated pointers. Error remain the same