# Reading string from input file and storing them into a dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I wrote a Code that reads string input from a file then stores them into a dynamic allocated array.

I believe that I have stored the elements correctly , however when I try to print out those elements I get a segmentation Fault.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

char reds [13];

int i;

    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;
        if(argc!=2){
            printf("[ERR]");
            return 0;
        }

   for (i =0; i < 13; i++) {


      char *reds = malloc (sizeof(char)); 
    fscanf (file, "%s", &reds[i]);
  }


      for (i =0; i < 13; i++){
    printf (" %s\n", reds[i]);

  }
    return 0;   

   }
```

input file:

```
RED A
RED 2
RED 3
RED 4
RED 5
RED 6
RED 7
RED 8
RED 9
RED 10
RED J
RED Q
RED K
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> char reds [13];
> ```

This allocates a fixed-size character array with 13 elements; it can hold a single string up to a length of 12 `char`s (plus the NULL terminator). That's not what you intended.

> ```
> char *reds = malloc (sizeof(char));
> ```

This creates a *new* variable `reds` which *hides* the one you declared above. This one is a pointer to an array with enough room for only a single `char`; it can hold only an empty string (the NULL terminator). That's also not what you intended.

> ```
> fscanf (file, "%s", &reds[i]);
> ```

This passes `fscanf()` a pointer to the `i`'th element of the (original) `reds` array. Since `reds` has 13 elements, that means if the string stored by `fscanf()` has more than `12 - i` characters in any loop iteration, the behavior will be undefined. Again, not what you intended.

---

What you probably meant to do was something like this:

```
char *reds[13]; // an array of 13 POINTERS

// later, in your loop...
reds[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (max_string_length + 1));
fscanf(file, "%s", reds[i]); // see note below
```

1) Don't forget to `free()` the pointers you allocate with `malloc()` or your program will have a memory leak. In your example it doesn't matter so much because the program exits right away (releasing the memory), but if it didn't that memory would be leaked, so you should develop good habits.

2) It's still possible to invoke undefined behavior, if `fscanf()` stores a string longer than `max_string_length`; you can improve this further by [passing a maximum width specified to `fscanf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf).

3) `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to equal 1, so you can omit this if you want (although there's no harm in leaving it in for clarity if you prefer this).

4) Do error-check the return values of `malloc()`, `fscanf()`, `fopen()` etc. If you don't, and an error occurs, your program can easily go on to invoke undefined behavior, which can be difficult to debug. Save yourself a lot of pain and develop this habit now.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have one more question. When I print out the array elements the output looks like this `red\nk`  how can I change this? I want it to print out like this  `redk`

Comment: and when I want to print out those elements I have to increase the array size to 26

Comment: I think I know why it stores the Value for example A into an array aswell