# how do i validate phone number in C programming

Tags: c

I'm trying to validate a 7 digit number C program . Where do i need to start
for example if less than 7 digit entered or more than 7 entered it ask to re enter a valid 7 digit

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`scanf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf) to read in (limiting the number of characters to read in), and [`strnlen()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html) to test for string length size:

```
char buf[10] = {0}; // Adding a little extra
do
{
  printf("Enter a phone number# ");
  scanf("%10s", buf);
  if(strnlen(buf, 10) != 7)
  {
    printf("Invalid phone number size provided!\n"); // Do some special error handling
  }
}while(strnlen(buf, ) != 7);
printf("I got a phone number now!\n");
```

Note, you might want to try testing for other error cases, like a mixture of letters and numbers, symbols, etc.

Previously, I answered this for C++ users (dunno what I was thinking, my bad...), but I think it's worth considering the options. In this case, onsider capturing the input as a `std::string`; this has a [`size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) method. For example, you could have something like this:

```
std::string phoneInput = "";
do
{
  std::cout << "Enter phone number# " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> phoneInput;
  if(phoneInput.size() != 7)
  {
    std::cout << "Invalid phone number, please try again!" << std::endl;
  }
}
while(phoneInput.size() != 7);
```

The key difference here is that C++'s string library dynamically allocates and resizes the string, so there's little concern for potential memory overruns. In C, however, if we're not careful to check the input size, `scanf()` could easily overflow the buffer itself (without the security string).

Comment: I don’t know if the question originally had a C++ tag, but if it didn’t, a C++ answer isn’t much help.  I don’t see signs of an edit from an iPhone and the app.

Comment: @Angelo — not my answer.  You should remove the `@` bit to address jhill515.

Comment: //here is  my attempt at it 
int PhoneNumber(){


int phoneInput ;

  printf( "Enter phone number# ");
 scanf("%s", &phoneInput);
 while(sizeof(phoneInput) != 7)
{
  if(sizeof(phoneInput) != 7)
  {
   printf("Invalid phone number, please try again!");
   scanf("%s", &phoneInput);
  }
}


if(sizeof(phoneInput) == 7 ){
        printf("thanks");
}

}

Comment: @jhill515  thanks but this is C++ code you gave me . I need to be able to do it in C

Comment: Whoops! It was a little late last night. I edited the answer, but preserved the C++ implementation as well. I hope you can appreciate the discussion at the end comparing both implementations.

Comment: @jhill515 thanks for the attempt it's still not working after entering a proper 7 digit number it keep looping and asking to enter a proper number :(

Comment: The width specified in `scanf("%10s", buf);` is incorrect: for a 10 byte array, it should be `scanf("%9s", buf);`. No reason to use `strnlen` instead of `strlen`

Comment: All that you've done is made sure that `scanf()` is limited to reading 9 characters. There are other ways to overflow `buf`, so I still recommend using the more secure `strnlen()` over `strlen()`.

Comment: @jhill515: you can use `strnlen()` if you insist, but at least correct the format string, test the `scanf()` return value and fix `}while(strnlen(buf, ) != 7);`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1, read a *line* of input

```
char buffer[100];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
```

2: parse it.  Use `"%n"` to note offset of scan location. `"%8[0-9]"` to look for up to 7 + 1 digits.

```
  int n;
  n = 0;
  char number[9];
  sscanf(buffer, " %8[0-9] %n", number, &n);
  if (n == 0) return fail; // no digits
  if (buf[n]) return fail; // junk after the digits
  if (strlen(buf) != 7) return fail; // not 7 digits
  Success();
}
```