# Iterating variable-length string in C

Tags: c, string

Iterating through a fixed-length string is easy, but when a variable-length string is used, the iteration fails after 0-th index.

For example, in the code below (printing characters of a string `p` one-by-one), using `p[]` doesn't work, while `p[some integer]` work (but we don't always know what that `some integer` is).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    // variable p to store string
    // if you change the line to let's say char p[20]=""; it will work
    char p[]="";
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", p);

    printf("You entered: %s\n", p);
    printf("String length: %d\n", strlen(p));

    printf("Printing each character of the string:\n");
    int i=0;
    while (p[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("p[%d] is %c\n", i, p[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length)

Comment: Besides the buffer overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf - so even with `char p[20]` you would need `%19s` in the `scanf` to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an array is not given an initial size, it is made exactly large enough to hold what it is initialized with.  In this case, you initialize a `char` array with the empty string `""`.  This string constant consists of a single null byte, so `p` is an array of size 1.

Then when you attempt to read a string into it you write past the end of the array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

If we omit the array dimension, compiler computes it for us based on the size of initialiser.

In this statement:

```
char p[]="";
```

the initialiser is an empty string literal (string literal with only a `'\0'` character). So, the size of `char` array `p` will be `1`.
Accessing an array beyond its size is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). An undefined behavior includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.