# Does scanf width modifier account for the null terminator when used with strings?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, scanf

For example, does this code allow for the maximum size string that this array could store to be entered? (255 characters of input from scanf, and then leaving room for a null terminator to be added)

```
char string[256]
scanf("%255s", string);
```

Or does the scanf function automatically add the null terminator to the end of the input meaning that in order to allow for 255 characters plus a null terminator I would want to specify a width of 256 in the scanf function, like so?

```
char string[256]
scanf("%256s", string);
```

Any help would be appreciated, and this is my first question on S/O so if I have done something wrong please let me know! :)

Comment: You use `scanf` wrong in both cases. First of all it doesn't [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) what you think it does. Secondly it does add the null-terminator, but it can't extend the array in any way. So reading 256 character *plus* the terminator will write the terminator out of bounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read no more than size of string with scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf)

Comment: The length limit is the number of actual characters read from the input, it doesn't include the null terminator.

Comment: The first version is correct, the second is wrong.