# while I comment the dynamic memory allocation command it doesn't work while it works fine if both the line are included . Why?

Tags: c

Here if I comment out both the dynamic memory allocation lines the code does not work whereas it works fine if both the lines are included . Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    struct data
    {
        char *a; 
        char *b;
    } p;

    printf("\n%lu\n", sizeof(struct data));

    // p.a=(char *)malloc(1);
    // p.b=(char *)malloc(1);

    printf("Enter a string ::");
    scanf("%s", p.a);
    printf("Enter another string ::");
    scanf("%s", p.b);

    printf("\n%s", p.a);
    printf("\n%s", p.b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You allocate only room for one char in a and b. Even if this seems to work, the program is using memory that has not been allocated!

Comment: because without allocation `p.a` and `p.b` can point to some random (and inaccessible) locations in memory

Comment: in a structure doesn't it allocate memory to all its members

Comment: See here for how to allocate and use scanf safely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf

Comment: @Nishant it allocates space, but it's a pointer, not a string.

Comment: a pointer takes 4 bytes right?

Comment: @Nishant no, a pointer does not necessarily take 4 bytes. It depends on your platform.

Comment: @Nishant: Your edit replaced your code with completely different code that made the answer not make sense.  Please don't do that.  I have rolled it back. If you have a question about a different piece of code, please ask a new question instead.

Comment: I can't understand but stackoverflow is not letting me to

Answer (score 0):

You either need to statically allocate storage for the scanf captured string or dynamically. In any case you need to ensure scanf does not capture more than what you allocated for.

Static allocation:

```
#define MAX_STRING 64
struct data_stat
    {
        char a[MAX_STRING]; 
        char b[MAX_STRING];
    } p;
```

or dynamically as you started to do:

```
struct data_dyn
{
    char *a; 
    char *b;
} ;
...
struct data_dyn p;
p.a = (char*) malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
```

Then you need to ensure scanf strictly capture MAX_STRING-1 chars at max. Last char of a string in C is always `\0`.
In both `data_stat` and `data_dyn` the field `a` and `b` contain a (char*) address stored on 4 bytes (pointer). What differs is the "range" covered by the array pointed to by the pointer. In `data_stat` the allocated memory is part on the `data_stat` structure itself, in `data_dyn` the allocated memory is on the heap.

See here for scanf details: [Read no more than size of string with scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf)

Comment: See if I used a character pointer(which has a size of 4 bytes )then why do i need to initialize it again

Comment: why wouldn't that be use rather than declaring it dynamically

Comment: `scanf` write into memory at the adress you provide (`p.a`). It writes as many chars as the user enters. You need to allocate enough storage for that many chars.

Comment: a pointer just stores the base address

Comment: so a character pointer should just store the base address of the string .

Comment: Pointer is the base address, the scanf write at base_add, base_add+1, base_add+2,.... You need to reserve those "addresses" upfront

Comment: why don't i have to do that if i use char pointer outside a structure

Comment: outside a structure it works properly without any dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Not it does not work either. You are writing anywhere in memory. This kind of code will crash eventually. You can check it by declaring `char *a,*b,*c,*d ; scanf(...,d); scanf(...,a)` You will see that d content is overwritten by a.

Comment: Yes ,it crashes for more pointers but works for a single pointer

Comment: but i still can't understand how you mean to say pointers allocation work

Comment: please help me sir

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: The `(char*)` before `malloc` is useless. Don't teach this bad habit.

Comment: malloc returns a void pointer type so it has be casted . shouldn't it be like that?

Comment: Hello @Jabberwocky. I tend to disagree on your comment. See here why: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM02-C.+Immediately+cast+the+result+of+a+memory+allocation+function+call+into+a+pointer+to+the+allocated+type

Comment: @Nishant no. Void pointer are safely promoted to any other pointer type.

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle I tend to disagree too. Taking the example on the link you provided: `p = malloc(sizeof(gadget));` should be written `p = malloc(sizeof(*p));`: no cast needed, no error possible.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I simply referenced the CERT (C Secure Coding Standard) whose scope is described here: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/Scope and is applicable to C11. I agree that your proposal addresses the risk of misalignment between allocated size and actual pointed variable type though ;-)