# can not get dynamic string allocation to work

Tags: c, string, malloc

hey guys i have looked around for a solution and tried everything i can think of im new to pointers and dynamic strings and i could really do with some help with problem. im currently learning c and i need to get the user to input a dynamic size for the string length . i need to make it so the users input can not be bigger then 100 . here's where i am at currently . i have the code booting but if i try set the size to let's say 5 i can still input way more chars into the string. cheers really appreciate any help .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    int  maxSize = 100; 
    char *name = (char*) malloc (maxSize * sizeof (char));
    int n; 
    char text1[]= ("input string size\n");

    printf ("your string lenght is %d\n", strlen(name));

    //getting size 
    n=intPrintScanner(text1);
    printf ("your size is %d\n",n);

    name = realloc (name,  sizeof (char) * n);

    //printing results 
    printf ("your string lenght is %d\n",strlen (name));
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("your string is %s",name);

    free(name);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("press any key to close");
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your use of `strlen()` is wrong. Thaf function does not return the size of the allocated buffer but the length of the string you've copied into it. You haven't copied any, so it invokes Undetined Behaviour. There's no way to determine the size of an allocated buffer afterwards so you have to stick to the values you've passed to `malloc()` and `realloc()`

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior, and `getchar()` reads a single character, but requires pressing the Enter/Return key, so "press any key to close" is misleading.  Is your main question how to prevent `scanf("%s", name);` to read more characters than fit in the allocated memory? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12908721/10622916 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/44663029/10622916

Comment: We can help you if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74152019/edit) your question with proper English capitalization. Then let us know if you can use POSIX `getline()`.

Comment: Does your C implementation of `scanf` allow for `%ms`? It's extremely convenient, albeit not standard.

Answer (score 2):

Bugs:

- You never assign any data to `name` so it just contains garbage. You can't use `strlen` on it before you have stored valid data there either. You can store a string inside `name` by for example using `strcpy`.
- When using `realloc`, there's no guarantee that the old pointer is the same as the returned pointer. Also, you need error handling. Implement it like this instead:

  ```c
  char* tmp = realloc (name, n);
  if(tmp == NULL) 
  { 
    /* actual error handling here in case realloc fails */ }
  }
  name = tmp; // assign pointer to the new area only if allocation succeeded
  ```
- `fflush(stdin);` is not well-defined, never use `fflush` on input streams. Instead you should discard unwanted line feed characters from `stdin` - which could be as trivial as an extra `getchar()` call just after reading something. Check out [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq) for lots of general good advise regarding how to take input from `stdin`.

Cosmetic/style:

- No need for parenthesis here: `char text1[]= ("input string size\n");`. All it achieves it to make the code look strange.
- The correct form of main is `int main (void)`. The `int main()` is obsolete style.
- There is no need to wrap the expression passed to `return` in a parenthesis.
- There is never a need to multiply something with `sizeof (char)`, since `sizeof (char)` is by definition always `1` no matter system.
- There is no need to cast the result of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* read_until(int fd, char end) {
      int i = 0, size;
      char c = '\0';
      char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

     while (1) {
          size = read(fd, &c, sizeof(char));

          if (c != end && size > 0) {
              string = (char*)realloc(string, sizeof(char) * (i + 2));
              string[i++] = c;
          } else {
              break;
          }
      }

                string[i] = '\0';
        return string;
 }

int main()
{
        char *name;
        int correct=0;

        do{
                write(1,"Put a name: ",strlen("Put a name: "));
                name = read_until(STDIN_FILENO,'\n');

                if(strlen(name) > 99){
                        write(1,"Error\n",strlen("Error\n"));

                }else{
                        correct=1;
                }

        }while(correct != 1);

        write(1,name,strlen(name));
       
        free(name);

}
```

Try using write and read instead of printf and scanf, it is better for allocating dynamic memory, read and try to understand the read_until function, there are better ways to do main.

Comment: I think the OP would learn more by explaining and fixing the errors in the original code than by providing a completely different implementation without much explanation. Why is `read` better than `scanf` with a size limitation or `fgets` (or even `getchar`)? Why is `write` bettern than `printf` or `puts`? As far as I understand the question, the requirement is to enter the maximum size first, then making sure the string input does not exceed the size.

Comment: `read` and `write` are not available in the C standard.

Comment: If `read` was available in the language proper, it is a terrible idea to suggest using it to read a single character at a time.  Especially to a beginner.

Comment: You could produce this same code with `fread` and `fwrite` with minimal changes, but showing this with `getchar` would be more helpful to the OP