# Overflow error message being shown after running the program code smoothly

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, runtime-error, buffer-overflow

So, I have been creating a function that takes input as a string and checks it with the test function that accepts exactly the length of the arguments being passed to the function but every time I run it there's some kind of run time error being displayed on the terminal but the program runs after I close it.
The error message:
[image]

The test case is this:

```
void test06_inputCString(void) {
char cstringValue[7] = { '\0' };

// Test explicit string length
printf("TEST #6: - Instructions:\n"
       "1) Enter the word 'horse'   [ENTER]\n"  // too short
       "2) Enter the word 'chicken' [ENTER]\n"  // too long
       "3) Enter the word 'SENECA'  [ENTER]\n"  // just right
       ":>");

// You may want to comment the next line if you have not yet created the inputCString function:
inputCString(cstringValue, 6, 6);

printf("////////////////////////////////////////\n");
printf("TEST #6 RESULT: ");
printf("%s (expected result: SENECA)\n", cstringValue);
printf("////////////////////////////////////////\n\n");}
```

My source code looks like this:

```
void inputCString(char* str, int minChar, int maxChar){
int i = 0, valid = 0;

while (valid != 1)
{
    scanf(" %[^\n]", str);
    int len = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    str[len] = '\0'; // Replace newline with null terminator

    if (len >= minChar && len <= maxChar)
    {
        valid = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (minChar == maxChar)
        {
            printf("ERROR: String length must be exactly %d chars: ", minChar);
        }
        else
        {
            if (len < minChar || len > maxChar)
            {
                printf("Error: String length must be between %d and %d chars: ", minChar, maxChar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Expected Output:
[image]

I think there's something with the way I'm assigning the string that's causing buffer overflow within the funtion but I don't seem to figure it out.

The below instruction needs to be satisfied for the function.

Function: inputCString
The purpose of this funcFon is to obtain user input for a C string value with a length (number of
characters) in the character range speciﬁed by the 2nd and 3rd arguments received (inclusive).

This function:
o must receive three (3) arguments and therefore needs three (3) parameters:
▪ 1st parameter is a character pointer represenFng a C string
Note: Assumes the argument has been sized to accommodate at least the upper- bound limit speciﬁed
in the 3rd argument received
▪ 2nd parameter represents an integral value of the minimum number of characters the user-entered
value must be.
▪ 3rd parameter represents an integral value of the maximum number of characters the user-entered
value can be.
o does not return a value, but does return a C string via the 1st argument parameter pointer.
o must validate the entered number of characters is within the speciﬁed range. If not, display an
error message (review the sample output for the appropriate error message).
Note: If the 2nd and 3rd arguments are the same value, this means the C string entered must be a
speciﬁc length.
o must conFnue to prompt for a C string value unFl a valid length is entered.
o guarantee’s a C string value is entered containing the number of characters within the range
speciﬁed by the 2nd and 3rd arguments (and return via the 1st argument pointer).

Comment: @Yunnosch sure, I did it.

Comment: As soon as you type a string with more than 6 characters, you have a buffer overflow and thus undefined behavior.

Comment: @nielsen any idea on how do i fix that . I’m new to c and I’m still learning things

Comment: The buffer `cstringValue` has size 7, which can hold 6 characters plus the terminating 0. You can increase this, but you should also limit the number of characters that can be entered. See answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf